# Is it possible to update just the Unity plugin in Compiz to the latest/greatest for testing?

Tags: unity, compiz, upgrade, testing

I am currently using Ubuntu 11.04 Natty.  Can I update, or upgrade, just the Unity Compiz plugin?

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

Unity consists of more than just a compiz plugin, and depends on several libraries that would require you to upgrade your system (unless you want to risk breaking everything).

I would suggest creating a Live CD or USB, or even testing 11.10 on a virtual machine if you have hardware powerful enough for it.